# Pointing one domain to the other using CNAME and keeping localization

Tags: domains, redirects, cname

Would I be able to have domain **b.com** point to **a.com/xyz** but for the user it should still appear as b.com? I won't be having any content on domain b.com it'll all be hosted on a.com and a.com/xyz respectively.

I've setup a CNAME before and it's straight forward, however I'm not sure if my request with keeping the URL while pointing to another domains content is possible.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to serve the content that's on `a.com/xyz` on `b.com`? 
Definitely possible but that's duplicate content and it's not something you want if you care about SEO.

Better go with one of these options:

1. simply 301 redirect from `b.com` to `a.com/xyz`.
2. serve the content only on `b.com`.
3. keep duplicate content and make sure the content on either `a.com` or `b.com/xyz` is not indexed by Google, you can do this in several ways (e.g. `robots.txt`, `noindex` tag) but none of them will be good in the long run.

If you still want to serve the exact same content you should look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you are using Apache.